Creating line that connects points from feature class to single point in another feature class using ArcGIS Pro
I wanted to connect origin and destination points using a line. The data are contained in an Excel spreadsheet which consists of two XY data (Origin & Destination). Here's a screenshot of an example:

As you can see, there are several origins that will connect to one destination.
I tried to use "XY to line" tool in ArcGIS Pro but it didn't work. I try to create separate point feature class for origin and destination but I don't how to connect it with a line.
Therefore, how do I connect origin points to a specified destination point using a line?
I also tried using HOW TO Create connection lines between points and a line in ArcGIS Pro but the method only connects the origin points to the nearest destination point.

1st method is a correct one, projection is an issue.

@FelixIP The XY to line tool didn't produce any line. Idk why. I tried both ArcGIS Pro and QGIS but the result was none. I used a projected coordinate system and already made sure that it's actually in that coordinate system.

Ok I made a dumb mistake. The XY to line tool is the way to go. I realized that my Destination coordinates are similar to origin because I forgot that the field calculator calculated X and Y coordinates from the origin position.

You should make public the way you made Excel and field calculator to work together
